# vscode dev container with prompt environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

For dev containers, [it is possible](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/environment-variables) to either provide env variables directly in `decontainer.json` or to provide a `decontainer.env` file. I wish to provide most of the variables via the env file but be prompted for input for a few sensitive ones to be available inside the container. This can be achieved for `launch.json` files using `VAR="{input:var_id}"`. I could not find a similar thing for `devcontainer.json`. I tried asking for user input in `postCreateCommand` and exporting it but it was not available when I attached a shell to the container.

Comment: I think you can use `postCreateCommand` to run a shell script to ask user to input the credentials and set the envrionment variable in the same script.